# Appending records in a datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've posted this elsewhere but my understanding of the requirement was incorrect to the moderator @ShaiCohen who was helping me suggested I repost it.

I need to edit the data that is fed to `DataTable` that can has varying columns and rows but the first two column are constant however. The data looks like this (numbers at beginning of the line are not part of the data):

```
    Repair  Repair 
    Code    Code Entries          6/1/2012  7/1/2012  8/1/2012  9/1/2012
    ------  --------------------  --------  --------  --------  --------
1.  00000A  Critical Down Time       1       
2.  00000A  Critical Outage          1       
3.  00000A  Total Repair Time        65         
4.  00000B  Critical Down Time                                     6
5.  00000B  Total Repair Time                                      90
6.  00000C  Critical Down Time       1          5    
7.  00000C  Critical Outage          1          5    
8.  00000C  Total Repair Time        30         240    
9.  00000D  Critical Down Time                                     2     
10. 00000E  Critical Down Time                          1    
11. 00000G  Critical Down Time                                     1    
12. 00000M  Critical Down Time        1                            3    
13. 00000M  Critical Outage           1                 3    
14. 00000M  Total Repair Time         60                180
```

Note that lines 1-3, 6-8, have the same Repair Code category and therefore are considered as group. On the other hand lines 10-12 have only "Critical Down Time" subcategory while the rest have combination of the three.

The requirement is to insert the "Repair Code Entries" subcategory where they aren't present. The reason they aren't present is because there is no data in the database, but the client wants to see the missing verbiage displayed even if there is no corresponding data and insert a empty row to separate the groups like this:

```
    Repair  Repair 
    Code    Code Entries          6/1/2012  7/1/2012  8/1/2012  9/1/2012
    ------  --------------------  --------  --------  --------  --------
1.  00000A  Critical Down Time       1       
2.  00000A  Critical Outage          1       
3.  00000A  Total Repair Time        65         

4.  00000B  Critical Down Time                                     6
    00000B  Critical Outage          
5.  00000B  Total Repair Time                                      90

6.  00000C  Critical Down Time       1          5    
7.  00000C  Critical Outage          1          5    
8.  00000C  Total Repair Time        30         240 

9.  00000D  Critical Down Time                                     2   
    00000D  Critical Outage          
    00000D  Total Repair Time
```

However the code that is currently in place assumes that the data has always the the grouping of three subcategories and so when it is no so the subcategory from previous row over writes the subcategory in the current row:

```
8.  00000C  Total Repair Time        30         240 

9.  00000D  Total Repair Time (should be Critical Down Time)        2   
    00000D  Critical Outage
```

In the code (below) the counter `subCategoryOccurences` inside `CheckSubCategoryRequirements` method doesen't get reset to zero when the new row is processed.

```
public void PrepareDataTable(DataTable dtResults)
{

    if (dtResults == null || dtResults.Rows.Count == 0)
       return;

    //initialize category
    categoryPrevious = dtResults.Rows[0]["Category"].ToString();
    do
    {
        //get the current category
        categoryCurrent = dtResults.Rows[rowCount]["Category"].ToString();
        //check if this is a new category. this is where all the work is done
        if (categoryCurrent != categoryPrevious)
        {
            //check if we have fulfilled the requirement for number of subcategories 
            CheckSubCategoryRequirements(dtResults);
            //at this point we have fulfilled the requirement for number of subcategories 
            //add blank (separator) row
            dtResults.Rows.InsertAt(dtResults.NewRow(), rowCount);
            rowCount++;
            //reset the number of subcategories
            subCategoryOccurences = 0;
            categoryPrevious = categoryCurrent;
        }
        else
        {
            rowCount++;
            categoryOccurences++;
        }
    } while (rowCount < dtResults.Rows.Count);
    //check sub category requirements for the last category
    CheckSubCategoryRequirements(dtResults);  
}




private void CheckSubCategoryRequirements(DataTable dtResults)
{
    if (subCategoryOccurences< subCategories.Length)
    {
        //we need to add rows for the missing subcategories
        while (subCategoryOccurences< subCategories.Length)
        {
            //create a new row and populate category and subcategory info
            rowFiller = dtResults.NewRow();
            rowFiller["Category"] = categoryPrevious;
            rowFiller["SubCategory"] = subCategories[subCategoryOccurences];
            //insert the new row into the current location of table 
            dtResults.Rows.InsertAt(rowFiller, rowCount);
            subCategoryOccurences++;
            rowCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to move the counter before the method call but that cuased a undesired results and so I'm not sure where to go from here. I would appreciate constructive comments. Thanks. R.

Comment: @ShaiCohen, per your request I re posted this.

Comment: This would be a lot easier if your table was normalized.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, it is not the question of normalization, the query uses a pivot so that the dates which are normally in a single column, are now displayed as column and the underlying data is calculated by the query.

Comment: My point is, it would be better to add the missing values pre-pivot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For these requirements, I took a different approach than previously. With these new requirements, we would have to "go backwards" to insert subcategories where they are previously missing.

This approach creates a *new* table that populates the correct number of subcategories for each category that is present in the original table. Once the new row is created, we then check the *old* table to see if there is any data we need to copy over to the *new* table (ie: "6/1/2012" and "7/1/2012" from your example).

Try this code:

```
public DataTable PrepareDataTable(DataTable dtResults)
{
    string[] subCategories = new string[3] {"Critical Down Time", "Critical Outage", "Total Repair Time"};
    //make a copy of the original table
    DataTable dtOutput = dtResults.Clone();
    DataRow drOutput = null;
    DataRow[] drResults = null;
    //retrieve the list of Categories
    var categories = dtResults.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r["Category"]).Distinct().ToList();
    //populate the new table with the appropriate rows (combinations of categories/subcategories)
    foreach (string category in categories)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < subCategories.Length    ; i++)
        {
            //create the new row in the new table
            drOutput = dtOutput.NewRow();
            drOutput["Category"] = category;
            drOutput["SubCategory"] = subCategories[i];
            //here is where you will check to see if a row with the same category and subcategory exists in dtResults. if it does, then copy over the values for each column
            drResults = dtResults.Select(String.Format("Category = '{0}' AND SubCategory = '{1}'", category, subCategories[i]));
            if(drResults.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach(DataColumn column in dtResults.Columns)
                {
                    drOutput[column.ColumnName] = drResults[0][column.ColumnName];
                }

            }
            dtOutput.Rows.Add(drOutput);
        }
        //add filler/spacer row
        drOutput = dtOutput.NewRow();
        dtOutput.Rows.Add(drOutput);
    }
    return dtOutput;
}
```

Here is the "test harness":

```
public void RunTest()
{
    DataTable dtResults = new DataTable();
    dtResults.Columns.Add("Category");
    dtResults.Columns.Add("SubCategory");
    dtResults.Columns.Add("Data");
    dtResults.Rows.Add("00000A", "Critical Down Time", "1");
    dtResults.Rows.Add("00000A", "Critical Outage", "1");
    dtResults.Rows.Add("00000A", "Total Repair Time", "1");
    dtResults.Rows.Add("00000B", "Critical Down Time", "1");
    dtResults.Rows.Add("00000B", "Total Repair Time", "1");
    dtResults.Rows.Add("00000C", "Critical Down Time", "1");
    dtResults.Rows.Add("00000C", "Critical Outage", "1");
    dtResults.Rows.Add("00000C", "Total Repair Time", "1");
    dtResults.Rows.Add("00000D", "Critical Down Time", "1");
    dtResults.Rows.Add("00000E", "Critical Down Time", "1");
    dtResults.Rows.Add("00000G", "Critical Down Time", "1");
    dtResults.Rows.Add("00000M", "Critical Down Time", "1");
    dtResults.Rows.Add("00000M", "Critical Outage", "1");
    dtResults.Rows.Add("00000M", "Total Repair Time", "1");
    DataTable dtOutput = PrepareDataTable(dtResults);
}
```

Comment: It almost works, all I get is first and second column - none of the values under the dates. I got a run, revisit in the morning. Again much thanks!

Comment: We're getting close! What happens when you run the "test harness" I provided? Do you get the "data" column? If so, try putting a breakpoint on this line `drOutput[column.ColumnName] = drResults[0][column.ColumnName];`. If the code goes in there, it _should_ add all the additional columns.

Comment: If I run `RunTest()` I get the values in the "Data" column.

Comment: In your code you're adding the "Data" column manually, whereas in my case the "Data" columns numbers can range from one to a large number.

Comment: This line `drResults = dtResults.Select(String.Format("Category = '{0}' AND SubCategory = '{1}'", category, subCategories[i]));
            if(drResults.Length > 0)` is always null on my case.

Comment: You need to change the column names (category and subcategory) to match your data table. Looking at your question, would they be "Repair Code" and "Repair Code Entries", respectively? Also, regarding the "data columns", the code dynamically adds **all** the columns. So if you have one data column or if you have ten, it will copy them all over.

Comment: For all intents and purposes your solution put me on the right course. As you may suspect I couldn't use the actual column names and variables due to company rules and as such the `"Total Repair Time"` is a much longer field and it throws a MaxLimit error when it reaches `dtOutput.Rows.Add(drOutput);` after the foreach loop. But that is a different topic. Thanks again!